# Caliburn.Micro partially fails to load views without code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I just recently noticed that Caliburn.Micro is sometimes unable to load a specific view if it's code-behind class is not present. This error occurs mainly on `UserControl` and `Window`.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create class "`ShellViewModel`" derived from "`Conductor`".
- Create `Page` "`ShellView`"
- Delete `ShellView.xaml.cs`

Result: **Caliburn.Micro successfully loads ShellView.xaml**

- Delete `Page` "`ShellView`"
- Create `Window` "`ShellView`"
- Delete `ShellView.xaml.cs`

Result **Caliburn.Micro is unable to locate `ShellView.xaml`**

What's the cause of this and how can I get completely rid of the code-behind classes? They do not hurt, I now, but they're unnecessary.

Comment: I've ran into the same thing trying to "clean" up my project. Would be nice to ditch all the code-behind classes. Did you ever find a solution?